# Coroutines kotlin not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I am using kotlin coroutines and have 2 problems -

1) My API call happens on `Main thread` which I actually want on `IO` and UI callback happens on `Main thread` which is fine.

2) `job.cancel()` doesn't seem to work. When the API call is in progress and I want to stop it, I call `stopAPICall()` but it seems to have no effect

```
class MyDetails(val callback: Callback,
                                   private val coroutineCtx: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) : KoinComponent, CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    private val repo: IRepo by inject { parametersOf(this) }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + coroutineCtx

    fun verifyMyDetails(id: String?) = launch {
        Log.e("TAG","Coroutines started =" + Thread.currentThread().name)  //Prints Main
        val response = repo.processId(id)

        when (response) {
            is APIResult.Success -> {
                Log.e("TAG","Updating UI =" + Thread.currentThread().name) //Prints Main
                callback.onSuccess(response.data.myDetails)
            }
            is APIResult.Error -> {
                callback.onAPIError(response.code)
            }
        }
    }

    fun stopAPICall() {
       job.cancel()
    }
}

class Repo(): IRepo {
    override suspend fun processId(id: String) {
       val response = apiInterface.processIdCall(id).await()
       try {
          return ...
       } catch(e: HttpException) {
          return ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Have a look at withContext() https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html , right now your Dispatcher is the main thread and you don't change it for the API request 2. If the API call doesn't take in consideration the status of the job then it will not react to its cancelling

Comment: Thank you...Got the first point working by adding withContext. But can you explain me in detail about point 2.